# How to connect smart trainer to Unity 3D

Tags: scripting

I am currently creating bicycle simulator where the user is pedaling and that controls the on-screen cyclist via Bluetooth.

However, I am unsure of how to go about doing so as I am still new to Unity. Is just enabling Bluetooth on Unity and connecting it to smart trainer sufficient to make it work? Or is a script required to enable this? Thanks.